# setInterval function not running on timed Interval, just repeating continuously with no time

Tags: ajax, jquery, setinterval, javascript

Just curious, I have this function:

```
setInterval( function(){
       sendAjax('search', eInput, function(responseText){
              $("#txtResp").html(responseText);
       })
}, 5000 );
```

It runs this function continuously, with no interval. It causes my sendAjax function to run like crazy.

I just need it to run every 5 seconds. Any help?

Regards,

Taylor

Comment: Is it possible your AJAX call is causing the setInterval line to be called? What happens if you replace the AJAX call with an alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doubt this is the problem, but don't forget to end your lines with a semicolon

```
setInterval( function(){
         sendAjax('search', eInput, function(responseText){
                $("#txtResp").html(responseText);
         }); // <---
 }, 5000 );
```

Also it could be a problem that just because you're doing something every 5 seconds, the callback to `sendAjax` will be executed when a response is received regardless of the interval. So you may be seeing consecutive responses repeatedly writing to the #txtResp div

Comment: Thanks for the change. But nevermind, my function works fine. It was an error later on in my code.